# Is it possible to test your app on iPhone 5 using the 3.5 inch form factor in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, iphone-5

When I am building an application for both the iPhone 3.5 inch & iPhone 4 inch, is it possible to test both form factors using the iPhone 5, instead of having to keep switching between phones?

I know that the iPhone 5 automatically puts black bars beneath and above any app that is not iPhone 5 compatible, but it would be great to be able to test apps in that way.

I doubt it's currently possible, as I haven't found any options for that in Xcode myself, but it would be awesome if Apple would add that feature. Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the `Default-568h@2x.png` from the project (just remove it's target membership) and clean the project you app is presented in 3.5 inch mode.

There is not way the set the run parameter too force it in 3.5 inch mode. You could also just connect both iPhones to you development machine and when you want to debug the app select the device you want to test on.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be enough to not supply a Default-586h@2x.png launch image. Just have Default.png and Default@2x.png, then the app should be letterboxed on the 4" simulator.